# Como rodar o Selenium e o Tkinter ao mesmo tempo sem parar de responder

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

Bom dia a todos! Possuo um código em python em que utilizo do Tkinter e o Selenium para pegar todos os livros que a amazon disponibilizou de graça recentemente, entretanto o Tkinter para de responder a medida que o Selenium abre, e eu gostaria de apresentar ao usuário a quantidade de livros que foram pegos e páginas que foram passadas, mas isso se torna inviável, visto que o tkinter não funciona, se alguém já tiver tido esse problema e puder ajudar ficarei grato.#Código abaixo#
ps: Caso tenha algo a comentar que possa melhorar o código pode dizer, estou aberto e melhorar. Obg.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox





class InstagramBot():
    def __init__(self, username, password, url, code):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.url = url
        self.code = code
        firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        firefoxProfile.set_preference("int1.accept_languages", "pt,pt-BR")
        firefoxProfile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enable", False)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(
            firefox_profile=firefoxProfile, executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gecko\geckodriver.exe"
        )

    def login(self,):
        try:

            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.br/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com.br%2Fref%3Dnav_signin&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=brflex&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&")
            loginusuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")
            loginusuario.clear()
            loginusuario.send_keys(self.username)
            buto = driver.find_element_by_id('continue').click()
            passwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//input[@name='password']")
            passwd.clear()
            passwd.send_keys(self.password)
            time.sleep(2)
            buton = driver.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit').click()
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            time.sleep(60)
        try:
            buton = driver.find_element_by_id('continue').click()
            time.sleep(30)
        except:
            pass

        self.takebooks()

    def takebooks(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.url)
        self.a = 0
        time.sleep(1)
        while True:
            for n in range(1,1000):

                try:
                    clicar = driver.find_element_by_id('a-autoid-'+str(n)+'-announce').send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ENTER)
                    self.a += 1
                    print("Livro Pego({})".format(self.a))
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
                    time.sleep(1)
                    driver.close()
                    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
                    time.sleep(1)
                except Exception as error:
                    #print("----")
                    pass
            try:

                nextpage = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)

            time.sleep(3)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window1(root)
    root.mainloop()
class Window1():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("BotInstagtram")
        self.master.geometry("700x500")
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.user = StringVar()
        self.passwd = StringVar()
        self.url = StringVar()
        self.LabelTitle = Label(self.frame, text="BOT AMAZON FREE BOOKS", font=("verdana", 30), bd=20, justify=LEFT)
        self.LabelTitle.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=20, sticky=W)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Frames
        self.Loginframe1 = Frame(self.frame, width=500, height=150, bd=20, relief='ridge')
        self.Loginframe1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.Loginframe2 = Frame(self.frame, width=500, height=50, bd=10, relief='ridge')
        self.Loginframe2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #StringVar
        self.url.set('https://www.amazon.com.br/s?i=digital-text&bbn=5475882011&rh=n%3A5308307011%2Cn%3A5308308011%2Cn%3A5475882011%2Cp_36%3A5560478011%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A6406077011&dc&language=pt_BR&_encoding=UTF8&fst=as%3Aoff&linkCode=sl2&linkId=c74a3b3b1606b3a2c5d5249ccab38e13&primeCampaignId=prime_assoc_ft&qid=1591627747&rnid=6406076011&tag=ynv-20&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_browse-bin_2')
        self.code = StringVar()
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Frame1
        self.LabelUser = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="Nome", font=('arial', 15, "bold"))
        self.LabelUser.grid()
        self.LabeltxtUser = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="Nome", font=('arial', 15, "bold"), textvariable=self.user)
        self.LabeltxtUser.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.LabelPasswd = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="Senha", font=('arial', 15, "bold"))
        self.LabelPasswd.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.LabeltxtPasswd = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="Senha", font=('arial', 15, "bold"), show="*", textvariable=self.passwd)
        self.LabeltxtPasswd.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.Botar = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="URL", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'))
        self.Botar.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.LabeltxtURL = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="URL", font=('arial', 15, "bold"), textvariable=self.url)
        self.LabeltxtURL.grid(row=2, column=1)
        #self.Botarcode = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="Code", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'))
        #self.Botarcode.grid(row=3, column=0)
        #self.Labeltxtcode = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="Codigo", font=('arial', 15, "bold"), textvariable=self.code)
        #self.Labeltxtcode.grid(row=3, column=1)

        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Frame2

        self.TestarConta = Button(self.Loginframe2, text="Executar", width=10, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), command=self.Login)
        self.TestarConta.grid()
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Frame3
        self.duvida = Button(self.Loginframe2, text="?", width=6, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'))
        self.duvida.grid(row=0, column=1)


    def Login(self):
        name = (self.user.get())
        passwd = (self.passwd.get())
        url = (self.url.get())
        code = self.code
        self.lucasbot = InstagramBot(name, passwd, url, code)
        self.lucasbot.login()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Cara, quando eu tenho uma tela, e tenho que clicar num botão, e o que o botão faz demora a executar. Se estiver na mesma Thread da tela, a tela trava. O ideal é vc utilizar Threads diferentes, um para executar a tela e outra para executar o selenium. Ou vc pode criar uma segunda aplicação, que recebe os parâmetros da tela e chama ele pelo Tkinter passando os parâmetros e liberando o comando chamar. A ideia é basicamente essa.

Comment: Ahh ok, vou tentar ver essa parada de thread, e usar muito obrigado!